# Updating the assemblyIdentity version number in a manifest file automatically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, version, manifest

I'm writing a C++ application in Microsoft Visual Studio and have added a VS_VERSION_INFO version table in the resource script so as to include version information (including a version number which is automatically increased at every build through a VS plugin).

I also need to include a manifest file and, as described in [Application Manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the program's version needs to be included there as well. At the moment, I'm writing it (inside the assemblyIdentity string) into the project's property pages manually.

Is there a way to keep both version numbers automatically synchronized so that I won't have to check at each build (or, at least, at every release build) that they are in fact in sync?

Comment: But why do you need to do all that?

Comment: @Ajay Maintaining both version numbers in sync is a recommended practice (see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365319/is-it-necessary-to-change-the-assemblyidentitys-version-attribute-in-a-manifest>), especially if someone is dealing with shared assemblies (that's not my case, but (1) I wanted to learn if there was a way to do it, for future reference, and (2) it's a matter of coherence).

Comment: @Ajay The version number of an `assemblyIdentity` element within a `dependentAssembly` element must match the true version of the dependent assembly if that assembly is a managed component, I've found. And if that also happens to be a component built internally, the number needs to vary with every build. Therefore I too would like to know how to allow this to be variable.